# Objective C linker scoping

Tags: objective-c

I ran into a situation where I had the following two implementations located in separate files:

ClassA.m

```
@implementation ClassA 
int _x = 0;
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
@implementation ClassB
int _x = 0;
@end
```

When I compiled, the linker would state:

> objective c duplicate symbol __x....

My solution was to mark both variables as `static`.

Is it then true that all member variables of Classes are just munged into the symbol table without their implementing Classname prepended (unless you mark them as static)?  I'd find that hard to believe, otherwise I'd think using `static` would be the rule, not the exception...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've not declared instance variables of the class there; you've declared global variables hence why the linker tells you that there's 2 symbols called `_x`.

You probably wanted to put them in your `@interface` for `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

Comment: Ahhh! I'm a bit new to the language details, I've been hacking a while on iOS apps and just came across this. I remember saying to myself "hmm, why would they duplicate the vars in the `@interface` seems like a waste of my time =)

Comment: so is the correct pattern to define the vars in the `@interface` and then initialize their values in `initWithNibName` (in the case of a UIViewController class?

Comment: In the case of iOS, with the recent development tools you *can* actually declare instance variables in the `@implementation` block; just wrap them in curly braces. `@implementation ClassA { int _x = 0; } @end`

Answer (score 1):

Instance variable would be declared in the implementation file of your class, in the header file.  You'll want the two class files to have something like this:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
    int _x;  // or NSInteger _x;
}
```